# How to use charlist wildcard in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to find the records where the first letter of the last name is between 's' and 'z'.
This is how I was trying to do this:

```
WHERE UPPER(last_name) LIKE '[S-Z]%'
```

I know someone will ask, so yes there are records in the database that the last name starts with one of these letters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use regular expression syntax with a normal `like`, but you can use `regexp_like` instead:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(UPPER(last_name), '^[S-Z]')
```

Or a slightly more brute-force approach:

```
WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(last_name, 1, 1)) BETWEEN 'S' AND 'Z'
```

or even more explicitly:

```
WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(last_name, 1, 1)) IN ('S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z')
```

Comment: Eliminating `UPPER` call ,by `REGEXP_LIKE(last_name, '^([S-Z]|[s-z])')`

Answer (score 2):

We can user the REGEXP function like this  and it will improve the performance also -

```
select * from your_table where REGEXP_LIKE(upper(last_name),'^[S-Z](*)');
```